# View BSAVE/BLOAD Image File in Windows?

Tags: images, disk-operating-system

BSAVE files are essentially partial memory dumps from the "old" DOS days. I have some old files created using BSAVE and would like to open them with a windows image editing application...Does anyone know of such an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using FreeBasic to load and dump the files. You can see the thread including the code utilized here: http://www.freebasic.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12554&highlight=

Answer (score 1):

I believe the format of BSAVEd files is device-dependent, meaning it depends on the video card in use at the time of the BSAVE.  Do you have any more information about your files?

You might try [PicEm](http://www.wnymason.org/masons/software/picem.htm). It knows about many obsolete graphics formats.

Comment: Thanks, PicEm didn't work, but I did get a resolution...I'll post it momentarily.